# Magento: Creating an attribute where each option increases the cost

Tags: magento, attributes

I make horse equipment and offer embroidery on almost every item.

I can't seem to figure out how to do an attribute that offers options that increase the cost based on the lettering chosen.

Is this possible, or am I better to offer the embroidery as a separate product altogether?

The embroidery does not affect the weight of the final product.

Answer (score 0):

Use of custom options would fulfill this requirement for you. See this screen shot for an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Cost" attribute for custom options is available in the [Advanced Product Options extension](http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html)